# Select field as input group addon

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, html-select, html-input

I want to use a `<select>` field as a input group addon with Bootstrap3 somehow like this

```
 -------------------------------------
|   select v   |   input text field   |
 -------------------------------------
```

So I would assume to achieve this using the `.input-group`, `.input-group-addon`, and `.form-control` classes.

```
<div class="input-group">
    <select class="input-group-addon" id="protocol">
        <option>http://</option>
        <option>https://</option>
    </select>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="domain" aria-describedby="protocol">
</div>
```

([See bootply example](http://www.bootply.com/NwRvndbYtP))

But the `.input-group-addon` class doesn't seem to work for `<select>` items. It looks like this:

[image: Screenshot]

How can I fix to properly align this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You just need to wrap your `<select>` by a `<div>` with class `.input-group-addon` like this

```
<div class="input-group">
  <div class="input-group-addon">
    <select class="" id="protocol">
      <option>http://</option>
      <option>https://</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <input class="form-control" id="domain" aria-describedby="protocol" type="text">
</div>
```

[Example](http://www.bootply.com/qZcUbw0Aeo)

Answer (score 2):

After struggling with this for a couple hours, I was able to find two solutions to get a result like this:

[image]
The best solution is to upgrade to bootstrap 4.0+. By upgrading to 4.0 you can simply do this and everything will line up nice and pretty ([v4.0 demo](http://jsfiddle.net/maxshuty/fmha310r/)):

```
    <div class="input-group">
       <input type="text" class="form-control"/>
       <select class="input-group-addon">
           <option>Option 1</option>
           <option>Option 2</option>
       </select>
    </div>
```

Since upgrading isn't always so simple of you are on Bootstrap v3 here is how you would do it ([v3.x demo](https://jsfiddle.net/maxshuty/7dnx2smr/8/)):

```
    <div class="custom-input-group input-group">
       <input type="text" class="form-control"/>
       <select class="custom-addon input-group-addon">
           <option>Option 1</option>
           <option>Option 2</option>
       </select>
    </div>
```

Then in the CSS our custom styles looks like this:

```
.custom-input-group {
  position: relative;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -ms-flex-align: stretch;
    align-items: stretch;
    width: 100%;
}
```

This will give us a select box that is lined up next to an input like the traditional `input-group-addon`'s.

Finally you will likely need to resize the width of the drop down:

```
.custom-addon {
/*You will need to add media queries to make this responsive.*/
 width: 28%;
}
```

Comment: Also note that for the 3.x solution, button addons are 1px wide, so if you have a button addon in the group, you should set the width to auto to avoid the button overflowing the flex box.